# Is "non-freedom" correct?

Tags: formality, negation, dashes

I need to write something like

> Students were silenced because of social media posts: a case of non-freedom.

That isn't the exact context, but I need to know if *non-freedom* is correct.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a common term, but if you want to invent then fine - that's what freedom is all about!

More typically you would say "oppression".

Comment: Disagree .. "oppression" is overly dramatic. It also implies a physical or active confrontation as well, unless being used by a liberal, in which case it means nothing because the liberals call any action with which they disagree "oppression".

Comment: Oppression may (to you) *imply* physical confrontation, but that isn't its definition. It simply means an excessive, unjust use of authority.

Comment: Yes thats why I voted up sam's answer - you should too

Answer (score 1):

Your example could have a multitude of mitigating circumstances both as to who was doing the silencing and why, and also what they were saying. So this won't be definitive, but typically stories like these make reference to "**violations of their rights/right to free speech**".  Oppression, as suggested by Martin, seems pretty vague in this limited context. **Censorship** would fit better.

Comment: in this context "censorship" is better

Answer (score 0):

No.  "Lack of freedom" is the usage which most tracks to "non-freedom".

One correct formulation in a sentence is:

> A clear case illustrating the lack of freedom is the silencing of
>   students posting on social media sites.